# objective c libraries on ubuntu

Tags: objective-c, gcc, gnustep

I installed GNUStep on Ubuntu 12.10, and some tools for Objective-C development. I then tried to compile the following code.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int *argc, const char *argv[]) {
  NSAutorelease *pool = [[NSAutorelease alloc] init];
  NSLog(@"hello world");
  [pool drain];
  return 0;
}
```

When I compile it with `gcc -o hello hello.m -Wall -lobjc`, I get the following error.

> Foundation/Foundation.h: No such file or directory; compilation terminated.

I find the Foundation library and other libraries in /usr/include/GNUstep/Foundation. Why am I getting that error message?

Comment: Can you show `hello.m`.   My first guess is that you used `#include "Foundation/Foundation.h"` not `#include <Foundation/Foundation.h>`.

Comment: Look here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=890425  also make sure that you have gnustep installed.

Comment: You should build it with GNUstep-make package which use GNUmakefile and here's how to write one http://www.gnustep.it/nicola/Tutorials/WritingMakefiles/index.html And if you want Objective-C 2.0, arc, literals, all the neat stuffs you should switch to clang.